# Identifying Vintage LEGO Instructions

Tags: instructions, vintage

I bought a box of old LEGO from the charity shop and the instruction booklet is missing the front page so, I’m struggling to find out information on it and how old it is! Can anyone help?!

[image]

[image]

Comment: The only set I could find that was even close to all of the pieces shown in the pictures was set #088-1 "Super Set". The bushes (#FTBushH) had me stumped. Glad Rin Rio-Oki found your answer. I still can't get over the picture showing a build that appears to be "black face". Very different times. (Edit: had posted wrong set number previously.)

Comment: No worries I was completely stumped too. It is that booklet however unfortunately there are lots of missing pages and it’s help together by cellotape!

Comment: @JohnnyB given the clue we were given that the tires only existed in 20 sets, I'm suspecting it might be [#190-1 Farm Set](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=190-1).

Comment: @Doktor J - I know what you mean, I considered that set too.  The lack of "Homemaker" figures, red 2x4 45 slopes, and 60's style bushes had me convinced it wasn't the correct set.  The #715a 12 stud wheel with cam in set #088-1 is nearly identical and works perfectly fine with the 2x4 wheel holders.  Given the book in question likely features a variety of sets, I'm glad Rin Rio-Oki found the answer or I'd probably still be looking ;)

Answer (score 15):

These are instructions from "*LEGO Books - Idea Book #1* or 221", that was released in 1973.

YouTuber *BrickTsar* uploaded his entire childhood book *[HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vFb673vvT7g)*.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Similar to the LEGO Idea books I had as a kid in the late 80's, these types of books were made with multiple sets in mind.

So, there isn't a focus on one specific set. The focus was you nagging your parents on what was vital for your next birthday.

Comment: What a wonderful video! Nice find and great answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

The big red wheel on the blue tractor was included in sets 1963-1975: [Wheel Old with 12 Studs](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=1594#T=C). There are only a twenty sets the big wheel appeared in, so you can look through the page linked above and see which set is the best match. My guess that it is one of the creative boxes with lots of bricks and alternate builds.

Comment: I’ve just found two of those wheels! Are they rare?

Comment: They only appeared in 20 sets and they are very old, so I would say yes, they are rare. Nice find! :)

Answer (score 1):

I have this book, also found it on [lego.brickinstructions.com](https://lego.brickinstructions.com/en/lego_instructions/set/221/Idea_Book_#1):

[image: Cover from Brick Instructios]

There is no "No.1" on mine. I also have an earlier Ideas book, so this not the first one.

[image: Step from question]

Comment: Lego has played fast and loose with numbering over the years.